# Unable to figure out the reason behind connection failure

Tags: api, wso2, activemq-classic

I am trying to send message to Queue on ActiveMQ from Wso2. Can anyone please help me with what wrong I am doing that I am getting this error?

```
[2022-11-10 18:20:22,324] ERROR {JMSConnectionFactoryManager} - Error setting up connection factory : jms:/WajihsCheck?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue
    org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.AxisJMSException: Cannot acquire JNDI context, JMS Connection factory : QueueConnectionFactory or default destination : null for JMS CF : jms:/WajihsCheck?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp&transport.jms.DestinationType=queue 
using : {java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp, java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=queue, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory}
```

For more clarity below is my service. Please guide:

```xml
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
    <format>
        <m:getQuote xmlns:m="http://services.samples">
            <m:request>
                <m:book>
                    <m:isbn>$1</m:isbn>
                    <m:release>$2</m:release>
                </m:book>
                </m:request>
        </m:getQuote>
    </format>
    <args>
        <arg expression="$.isbn" evaluator="json"/>
        <arg expression="$.year" evaluator="json"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
<property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
<call>
    <endpoint>
        <address uri="jms:/WajihsCheck?transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=QueueConnectionFactory&amp;
                      java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;
                      java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp&amp;transport.jms.DestinationType=queue"/>
    </endpoint>
</call>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `java.naming.provider.url` seems to be wrong.

```
java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:8161/admin/queues.jsp
```

It should be something like this, pointing to the AMQP port of ActiveMQ

```
java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: @WajihHaider Do you get the same error?